# Session management in sails js framework

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I'm new to sail's and node, I'm trying to create/maintain a session without user login. The user sends request to server and i'm trying to store the session by `req.session.uid="some uniqueid"`, and when again the same user tries for another request i'm unable to get the session. For every request a new session id is coming(session is not persisting).

please help by posting the code or by referring to already existing code.

Answer (score 2):

You should call `req.session.save();` at the end to persist the data.